# How to make sure memory leak is being taken care of?

Tags: memory-leaks

When does operating system deallocate memory? I don't see it being deleted when I use Performance counters. See the below code. The difference between Memory usage before allocation and Memory usage after de-allocation should be 0 but its not.

Basically I have a COM dll hosted in dllhost which leaks memory (more than 2GB on 32 bit MS-OS).

```
            #include "stdafx.h"
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <crtdbg.h>
        #include <list>
        #include <map>



        //#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <crtdbg.h>

        using namespace std;
        /*
        #ifdef _DEBUG
           #ifndef DBG_NEW
              #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
              #define new DBG_NEW
           #endif
        #endif  // _DEBUG
        */
        template <class K, class T, class Pr = less<K>, class A = allocator<T> > 
        class CTypedHeapPtrMap : public map<K, T, Pr, A > 
        {
        public:   
            // Construction
            CTypedHeapPtrMap()
            {
            };   

            // Destructor
            ~CTypedHeapPtrMap() 
            {
                DeleteContents();
            };  

            void DeleteContents() 
            {
                iterator ItEntry;

                /* Empty the list and delete memory */
                ItEntry = begin();   
                while (ItEntry != end())
                {

                    T pT = ItEntry->second;
                    delete[] pT;
                    pT = NULL;
                    ItEntry++;
                }
                map<K,T,Pr,A>::clear();
            };  
        };

        typedef CTypedHeapPtrMap<long, char*>                   VALIDATION_MAP;

        int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
        {
            PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmcx = {};

            pmcx.cb = sizeof(pmcx);
            GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(),reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmcx), pmcx.cb);

            //assumuing GetProcessMemoryInfo call above allocates some memory. So get the memory status again
            pmcx.cb = sizeof(pmcx);
            GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(),reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmcx), pmcx.cb);
            printf(" Memory usage (Before allocation) = %ld\n", pmcx.WorkingSetSize);

            {
                VALIDATION_MAP pStr;

                char *ptr1 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(1, ptr1));
                char *ptr2 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(2, ptr2));
                char *ptr3 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(3, ptr3));
                char *ptr4 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(4, ptr4));
                char *ptr5 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(5, ptr5));
                char *ptr6 = new char[10000];   
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(6, ptr6));
                char *ptr7 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(7, ptr7));
                char *ptr8 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(8, ptr8));
                char *ptr9 = new char[10000];
                pStr.insert(VALIDATION_MAP::value_type(9, ptr9));
            }
            pmcx.cb = sizeof(pmcx);
            GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(),reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmcx), pmcx.cb);
            printf(" Memory usage (After de-allocation) = %ld\n", pmcx.WorkingSetSize);
            Sleep(60000);//sleep for a minute
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Simple: Just dont create the leak

Answer (score 1):

The system will deallocate the memory after the program using that memory is terminated, i.e., after the `return 0` in your main. The memory has not been freed when your `GetProcessMemoryInfo` function is called, hence the large difference in memory usage when it should be zero. The system is in fact deallocating the memory (it always does), just after your program ends.

However, you should not feel like you're in the clear, you said the leak is 2GB of memory, that a LOT, I highly highly doubt your program needs that much memory to run. You really should consider finding places in your code to free memory for variables not being used.

Comment: VALIDATION_MAP pStr is going out of scope and hence the destructor gets invoked. Doesn't OS deallocates memory that time?

Comment: VALIDATION_MAP pStr is going out of scope and hence the destructor gets invoked. Doesn't OS deallocates memory that time? On 2 GB memory issue - I have a C++ code which calculates something based on some kind of optimisation. The optimisation is being carried out in a recurssive function. The function allocates memory on heap as and when it needs. The destructor suppose to free it. This particular dll is hosted in dllhost and the code is multithreaded. So if OS is deallocating only after program exit, then its no good for me.

Comment: You really should NOT rely on the OS deallocating memory for you, ever. C and C++ are low level and very powerful for a reason, you should take care of allocation and deallocation your self, its only guaranteed that the memory will be freed after program exits